# The rendering order of the React-raphael components (like z-index)

Tags: reactjs, raphael

I want the Raphael-react components to be drawn in the order I need (to create different layers or something like z-index). How can I control the position of components "Path" on the "Paper"?

This is a simplified view:

```
<Paper>
 <Set>
   <Path .../>
   <Path .../>
   <Path .../>
 </Set>             
</Paper>
```

Comment: Z-index in svg is just the order of elements added. If you want to move one element in front of another, just remove and readd into a later part of the tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Raphael doesn't support z-index, but you can achieve the goal if you keep all data in an array inside `local state` (or Redux):

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    { x: 50, y: 50, r: 40, attr: { stroke: "#0b8ac9", "stroke-width": 5 }},
    ... 
  ])
```

Then if you'll want change z-Index of element just move it in array:

```
  zIndexOrder = [ ..., -1, 0, 1,  ...] // last element has big z-index
```

I prepare demo for you with the Olympic Rings where I just shuffle them.

```
  const randomizeZIndex = () => {
    const temp = [...data];
    temp.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
    setData(temp);
  };
```

You can see it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/raphael-zindex-ygbx5)

Of course, `random` is useless. You need to maintain a `zOrder` on each element to work properly.

And if you want work with all figures you can add `polymorphism`. And save the element's type (circle, line, etc.)

```
const elements = [{
  type: "Rect",
  key: "FirstRect",
  zOrder: 0,
  options: {
     x:30, y:148, width:240,height:150, 
     attr:{"fill":"#10a54a","stroke":"#f0c620","stroke-width":5
   }
 }}, ...];
```

Code would be like this:

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
import { Raphael, Paper, Set, Rect, Line } from "react-raphael";

const RaphaelElement = {
  Line: function line({options}) {
    return <Line {...options}/>; // react-raphael Line
  },
  Rect: function rect({options}) {
    return <Rect {...options}/>; // react-raphael Rect
  }
}

const AllElements = ({elements}) => {
  return (
     <Fragment>
      { // with polymorphism
        elements.map(({options, key, type}) => {
          const CurrRaphaelElement = RaphaelElement[type];
          return <CurrRaphaelElement key={key} options={options} />
        })
      }
     </Fragment> 
  )
}
```